# Laravel Error :

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to setup laravel in my Windows system. I've installed composer. But there are some issues with the composer that is creating problems while trying to create a new laravel project.

I did a composer diagnose from the cmd and following are the results:

```
composer diagnose
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The       "https://api.github.com/rate_limit" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation   failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify    failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Laravel Error:

```
new laravel_demo_1
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 59 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
   - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.1.0): Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)    Failed to download doctrine/inflector from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/doctrine/inflector/zipball/90b2128806bfde671b6952ab8bea493942c1fdae" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code     1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify  failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Now trying to download from source
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.1.0): Cloning 90b2128806 from cache
  - Installing erusev/parsedown (1.6.1): Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)    Failed to download erusev/parsedown from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/erusev/parsedown/zipball/20ff8bbb57205368b4b42d094642a3e52dac85fb" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:......
```

Comment: laravel got nothing with it. It is all about composer

Comment: Do you have `ca-certificates` installed on your system?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski If it's related to composer, can you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: @tomudding how to check if ca-certificates are there?

Comment: see the answer i posted. Let me know it worked

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are simply hitting Github limits due to non authenticated access.

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The
>   **"https://api.github.com/rate_limit"** file could not be downloaded: SSL
>   operation   failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:

so it should be sufficient to just authenticate yourself:

1. Log into your GitHub account and click on "Applications" in the sidebar
2. Create a new token under the "Personal Access Tokens"
3. in project's folder do:

   - `composer config github-oauth.github.com YOUR-TOKEN`

and that should be it.